# AWS CloudFormation Template for customized windows AMI not running cfn-init and not creating the related files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Below is my template snippet in which Windows Custom AMI is used to create the server.
Here cfn-init.exe is not getting executed even if I have given it in the userdata block. As a result no files are gettting created in my server. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

```
"CMServer":{ 
"Type":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
"Metadata":{ "AWS::CloudFormation::Init":{ 
               "config":{ "files":{ "c:\\cfn
                                    cfn-hup.conf":{ 
                                     "content":{ "Fn::Join":[ "",[ "main\n","stack=",
                                       { "Ref":"AWS::StackName"},"\n","region=",
                                          { "Ref":"AWS::Region"},"\n",
                                            "interval=1"]]}},
                  "c:\\cfn\\hooks.d
                   cfn-auto-reloader.conf":{ "content":{ 
                               "Fn::Join":[ "",[ "cfn-auto-reloader-hook\n",
                                 "triggers=post.update\n",
                            "path=Resources.CMServer.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                              "action=cfn-init.exe -v -s ",{ "Ref":"AWS::StackName"},"                             
                             -r CMServer",
                             " --region ",
                               { 
                                 "Ref":"AWS::Region"},"\n"]]}},
             "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\AWSCM\\Website\\App_Config
            ConnectionStrings.config":{ 
            "content":{ 
             "Fn::Join":[ "",[ 
             "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n",
             "<connectionStrings>\n",
             "<add name=\"core\" connectionString=\"user id=user;password=******;Data Source=",
        { "Fn::GetAtt": },
          ";Database=CoreDb\"/>\n",
"<add name=\"master\" connectionString=\"user id=user;password=******;Data Source=",
{ "Fn::GetAtt": },
";Database=MasterDb\"/>\n",
"<add name=\"web\" connectionString=\"user id=user;password=******;Data Source=",
{ "Fn::GetAtt": },
";Database=WebdB\"/>\n",
"</connectionStrings>"
]
]
},
"mode" : "000644",
"owner" : "root",
"group" : "root"
}
},
"services":{ 
"windows":{ 
"cfn-hup":{ 
"enabled":"true",
"ensureRunning":"true",
"files":[ 
"c:\\cfn
cfn-hup.conf", "c:\\cfn\\hooks.d
cfn-auto-reloader.conf"
]
}
}
}
}
}
},
"Properties":{ 
"ImageId":{ 
"Fn::FindInMap":[ 
"AWSRegionArch2AMI",
{ 
"Ref":"AWS::Region"
},
"SitecoreCMAMI"
]
},
"SecurityGroupIds":[ 
{ 
"Ref":"CMServerSecurityGroup"
}
],
"SubnetId":{ 
"Ref":"PrivateSubnet1"
},
"InstanceType":{ 
"Ref":"CMInstanceType"
},
"KeyName":{ 
"Ref":"KeyName"
},
"UserData":{ 
"Fn::Base64":{ 
"Fn::Join":[ 
"",
[ 
"<script>\n",
"cfn-init.exe -v -s ",
{ 
"Ref":"AWS::StackName"
},
" -r CMServer",
" --region ",
{ 
"Ref":"AWS::Region"
},
"\n"
"</script>"
]
]
}
},
"Tags":[ `enter code here`
{ 
"Key":"Name",
"Value":"CMServer"
}
]
}
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solved the problem. the problem was with template JSON format. I tried with single quotes(') instead of double like
"\n",

. hence solved.

thank you for your response.

Comment: "I tried with single quotes(') instead of double like "\n"". Where??

Answer (score 0):

Prior creating your customized AMI, you need to enable the 'User Data Execution' from the 'EC2ConfigService Settings' at the instance from which you will create the customized AMI.

You can get to EC2ConfigSerice Settings from:
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Ec2ConfigServiceSettings.exe" then on the General tab, check 'Enable UserData Execution...' check box. Only then create the customized AMI.

A shortcut to the EC2ConfigService Settings is available on windows start view as well.

Comment: I have already tried but still not getting it work. The options which have been already tried,
1) Specified -c option both in the UserData and the cfn-auto-reloader.conf.
2) Enabled UserData execution when next service starts in EC2ConfigService Settings before taking the custom AMI from instance

Answer (score 0):

Check that your instance has access to the S3 service (access to the internet). 
In order for the machine to get the UserData it need to be able to connect to the internet. The Userdata, part of the cloudformation script is kept in the S3 service. an http call is made to the S3 for getting the UserData. According to the script you launch the instance is launched to a private subnet. I dont know by the snippet if it's really private but regardless the security groups attached, an instance launched into a VPC (to a subnet - not the default subnet), wont get a public IP.

If you need to access the internet you'll need to attach a NAT or assign an EIP and update the ACL/security groups if relevant.